# Unknown about QueryResult

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
public DataSet SelectSQL(String QueryString)
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            OpenConnection();
            DbCommand.CommandText = QueryString;
            DbCommand.Connection = DbConnection;
            dataAdap.SelectCommand = DbCommand;
            try
            {
                ds_QueryResult.Tables.Clear();
                dataAdap.Fill(ds_QueryResult, "QueryResult");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Errors.Add(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                DbConnection.Close();
                dataAdap.Dispose();
                DbCommand.Dispose();
            }
            return ds_QueryResult;
        }
```

I want to know the meaning of QueryResult in above code ..What is that ?

Comment: You should know, it's your code.

Comment: you miss to post the code where ds_QueryResult is defined. But i guess is a DataSet

Comment: It's not my code . I am trying to learn others code and regenerate the program .. DataSet ds_QueryResult = new DataSet();This is only the definition of ds_QueryResult. I am a beginnger in this field . I checked the database , there is no table with name QueryResult. But the program works .

Comment: Me to I was new, just look on google for DataSet .NET and you will find a lot of resources

Comment: Studying others' code is a good way to learn new techniques, however, you need to learn the basics first. If you don't even know what a dataset is, you will waste more time posting questions like this than if you took time for a bit of study. There are plenty of sources out there. Find one to your liking and use it.

Answer (score 1):

It will represent a name of data table within data set. So in  case of multiple tables in a dataset you can use by its name.

Comment: In case if there is not a table with name "QueryResult" in dataset . Will it be generated with the name "QueryResult" or I have to define the table name before ?

Comment: `QueryResult` Table should be created automatically if not exists.

Answer (score 0):

`ds_QueryResult` is [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx).

DataSet is collection of DataTables. Each table name in the dataset can be identified by its name. `QueryResult` here is datatable name in the `DataSet`. 
If `QueryResult` table is not present then it will be added into DataSet.

Check [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz.aspx) to `DbDataAdapter.Fill Method (DataSet, String)`.

From your comments it seems you are matching table name present in dataset with table name in database. Both are different. Check [MSDN Reference for DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx).

> DataSet is an in-memory cache of data retrieved from a data source.

Comment: This means I am filling an empty table in Data Set ? Please don't think this as a silly question , because I am in the beginner level and cannot grab all ..

Comment: You are filling data based on query present in `QueryString` parameter. It is select command.

Comment: Like to thank you for your answers and suggesting me to learn in depth  before code...

Answer (score 0):

these are different types of parameters you can pass to the "Fill" method it is called as method Overloading. 
next time if you want to know what are all the parameters inside that method

**dataAdap.Fill**
if you open the paranthesis it will show suggestions and you just need to press down arrow for all the methods overloaded in it.

it will show you all the methods overloaded on to that method

[image]